# How do I save the text in a textarea to the users computer when they click a button in html?

Tags: html, textarea, save

I am working on my blog again, but I want to make an online text editor where you click a button and it saves it to their computer, and if you click the load button it loads a file from their computer. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The security restrictions under which browsers work do not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to write to the filesystem of the client. This is for security reasons.

However, with JavaScript you can store some data (up to 5MB) in the `localStorage` object and retrieve it from there later on. [localStorage @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

The `localStorage` can only store strings in its key-value store, so you might have to serialize your objects before storing them.

Storing

```js
window.localStorage.setItem( 'yourId', JSON.stringfy( yourData ) );
```

Retrieving

```js
var yourData = JSON.parse(  window.localStorage.getItem( 'yourId' ) );
```

Comment: +1 This is admittedly more elegant and less steps than my solution, (though has the recognized potential to max out at 5 megs, but who's going to write a 5 meg plain-text file?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why there is so strong an *it's impossible* current with client-side storage: all you have to do is export the file as whatever format you want (even plain-text) and have the user download it -- akin to *Save As*. To load the file, have the user upload it again -- akin to *Open*.

This can be accomplished by posting the contents of the textarea to a php script, for example.

This is no more steps than using `Save As...` and `Open` dialogs in any other local word processing application.

The only reason you might want a user to do this, though, is to allow them to edit the file locally while they were disconnected from your blogging platform. So a more elegant alternative, unless you want the user to actually edit the file locally, is to save draft versions on the server (like StackExchange does).

Answer (score 0):

Loading can be implemented like this in a form (sending to a PHP-script for example):

```
<input name="usedFile" type="file" class="file" size="50"
       accept="text/csv,text/plain" />
```

This allows for example loading of text- and csv-files.

I think saving is not possible like this.

**@comment**
It really depends on what you want to do with the file. Here is a simple loading function:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['usedFile']['tmp_name'])) {
    load_uploaded_file($_FILES['usedFile']['tmp_name'], $my_loaded_data);
}

// ...

function load_uploaded_file($filename, &$data) {

    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        return False;
    }

    $data = array();
    $rowCount = 0;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

    while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== False) {
        $data[$rowCount] = $line;
        $rowCount++;
    }

    fclose($handle);  
    return True;
}
```

Comment: @EandCProducts I'm not implementing the whole functionality. I added a simple loading function. You have to do assertion or sth. else on your own and set the text for you html element.